# Angular2 online / offline event

Tags: angular, offline-browsing

Is there a native Angular2 event to notify when the application loses / regains network connectivity?

Or a wrapper for window.navigator.online / offlinejs?

Comment: No, the only thing I know of is https://github.com/HubSpot/offline

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such native api in angular2.